# Translate from SQL to relational algebra

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Hey I have been asked this question:

Translate the following SQL into relational algebra

```
SELECT DISTINCT Student.Name, Course.Name
FROM Student, 
     Attendee, 
     Course
WHERE 
        Student.Name = Attendee.Name 
   AND Attendee.CourseId = Course.CourseId 
   AND StudyCourse = ‘CS’ 
   AND Course.CourseId > 42 
   AND Year = 2011
```

I've tried to look around, but i can't really seem to find a specific answer on how to do so.

Comment: Search for "relational algebra". (Tip: the wiki page is huge)

Comment: Actually this is a maths question, and might be a good fit on mathematics.stackexchange

Comment: Looks somewhat of a homework. In this case you should have been provided information on relational algebra at class. As @Keyser suggests, do some research on this topic and try to solve it yourself, as otherwise you will not learn too much from this assignment.

Comment: i'm really trying to get it into any sense of meaning... but it says nothing about my "Select distinct" is it still just "pi"L(R) or do you specify it in another way?

Comment: I know so, and it is homework, but we haven't had any kind of translating course... we have been told a little about it, but not how to put into use, and we're far away from even mentioning this in math

Comment: Nominating to reopen the question.  This was closed as "not a real question" but it's as much a real question as a question about any other computer science theory, like algorithm complexity or information compression.

Answer (score 2):

> ---
>
> **Symbol meaning:**
>
> ---
>
> **σ**   : Selection
>
> **∏**   : Projection
>
> ⋈      : Join
>
> **Χ**  : Cartesian Cross
>
> ---
>
> **Answer:**
>
> #### **∏** <sub>Student.Name, Course.Name</sub> (**σ** <sub>(Attendee.Name=Student.Name) &&(StudyCourse = 'CS') && (Course.CourseId > 42)  && (Year = 2011)</sub> (Student **Χ**  Attendee **Χ** Course))
>
> .

One Difference is between SQL and Relation Algebra(RA) is SQL return Table where duplicate are allowed and need to explicitly remove whereas RA return set.

Comment: Ahh now I think I understand, but what happened to Attendee.Name=Student.Name?

Comment: Edit the Expression, may this time correct...anyway all condition come under select....Also this may be not optimised and efficient expression. Infarct more than one RA is possible for a query.

Comment: I know, I've just made it with join instead, and my instructor was much more pleased

Comment: Yes, Using Join is better then cross-product produce shorter intermediate results. There is a topic called Query Optimisation. quite interesting.

Comment: @user1731315 - this is the second question I have seen from you that has been answered, yet you do not mark it as the answer. Please do so or people will no longer help you on this site.

Comment: You can write RA expressions with Latex notation

Comment: @TegiriNenashi Can we write RA expressions with Latex notation here on OS!

Comment: @user1731315: Click right if feel like to be accepted .

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I am also having problems in Relational Algebra question. I have posted my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997845/how-to-convert-sql-to-relational-algebra-in-case-of-sql-joins). Can you please help me here? Thanks.

Comment: @SSH being busy in my study work I couldn't answer you I will answer you on weekend (if I could, if I find out answer)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Thanks a lot Grijesh.. I will be looking forward for your reply whenever you are free.. Thanks a lot for the help...

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Any luck so far?

Comment: @SSH Sorry for delayed answer, I was very busy in my own study. I posted an answer with some links. Please explore and learn about % operator in relational algebra